# Simple delay pedal with more headroom

Tags: guitar-effects, effects-pedal

I'm using a Mooer Reecho in my VOX AC30CC2 effects loop. Running the amp clean, it sounds great. However, I like to drive my amp into a mild overdrive, but my Reecho can not handle this. The pedal does not have enough headroom to cope with the volume boost. What can I do to drive my amp and use a delay pedal in the effects loop at the same time?

Comment: Does the AC30 have any level controls on the effects loop? This does sound like a product search question, which would be considered off-topic. Can you edit it to ask for solutions to your headroom problem general and remove the part about asking what pedals would help?

Comment: The AC30 has a -10dB/+4dB switch for the effects loop. I set it to -10dB. Thanks for your feedback. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer - attenuate your signal before if gets to the delay. I know you mention a -10dB attenuation on the AC30, but if that isn't enough just get an volume/attenuators pedal and pop it in the chain before your delay.

If you are more electronically proficient, you could try to alter your effect loop attenuation, but that will not be easy, and will mean future effects may suffer, so my recommendation would be to buy a pedal.